# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeUnknownConstraintError: Unknown constraint error

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am working with an API in NodeJs and Express to connect with a PostgreSQL database using Sequelize. When I run my program in the end of the Sequelize output in the terminal i got:

```
Executing (default): ALTER TABLE "installation_sites" DROP CONSTRAINT "installation_sites_contractor_id_fkey"
(node:21312) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeUnknownConstraintError: Unknown constraint error
    at Query.formatError (C:\Users\caleb\OneDrive\Documentos\Aplicativo_RDO\API\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\
postgres\query.js:376:17)
    at Query.run (C:\Users\caleb\OneDrive\Documentos\Aplicativo_RDO\API\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\
postgres\query.js:87:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
Executing (default): ALTER TABLE "installation_sites" ALTER COLUMN "contractor_id" SET NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE "installation_sites"  ADD FOREIGN KEY ("contractor_id") REFERENCES "contractors" ("contractor_id") 
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;
(node:21312) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeUnknownConstraintError: Unknown constraint error
    at Query.formatError (C:\Users\caleb\OneDrive\Documentos\Aplicativo_RDO\API\node_modules\sequelize\lib\
dialects\postgres\query.js:376:17)
    at Query.run (C:\Users\caleb\OneDrive\Documentos\Aplicativo_RDO\API\node_modules\sequelize\lib\
dialects\postgres\query.js:87:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:21312) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. 
This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, 
or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process 
on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` 
(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:21312) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. 
In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I don't understand what is causing this. Here are my models involved:

InstallationSite.js model:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require("../database/index");
const Contractor = require("../models/Contractor");
const JobPosition = require("./JobPosition");

class InstallationSite extends Sequelize.Model {}

InstallationSite.init(
  {
    installation_site_id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    installation_site_status: {
      type:Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull:false,
      validate:{
        isIn:[['Em Andamento', "Finalizada", "Não Iniciada"]]
      }
    },
    enterprise_name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    enterprise_start_date: {
      type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    enterprise_duration_days: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    enterprise_city: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    enterprise_state: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    contractor_id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: "contractors",
        key: "contractor_id",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: "installation_sites",
  }
);

InstallationSite.belongsTo(Contractor, {
  foreignKey: "contractor_id",
  targetKey: "contractor_id",
});
Contractor.hasMany(InstallationSite, {
  foreignKey: "contractor_id",
  sourceKey: "contractor_id",
});

InstallationSite.belongsToMany(JobPosition, {
  through: "contracts",
  foreignKey: "installation_sites_intallation_site_id",
  as: "positions",
});

JobPosition.belongsToMany(InstallationSite, {
  through: "contracts",
  foreignKey: "job_positions_job_position_id",
  as: "installations",
});

sequelize.sync({ alter: true });
module.exports = InstallationSite;
```

Contractor.js model:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require("../database/index");

class Contractor extends Sequelize.Model {}

Contractor.init(
  {
    contractor_id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    contractor_name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      validate: {
        is: {
          args: /[a-zA-z]/,
          msg: "Contractor name must contain only letters",
        },
        len: {
          args: [5, 50],
          msg:
            "Contractor name must contain at least five letters and less than 50 letters",
        },
        notEmpty: {
          args: true,
          msg: "Contractor name is not optional",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: "contractors",
  }
);

sequelize.sync({ alter: true });
module.exports = Contractor;
```

I would like to know if anyone can help me find out what is causing this warning.

[EDIT] The constraint `installation_sites_contractor_id_fkey` seems to exist inside the DB.

[image: Picture of DB content]

[EDIT2]

After a manually executed the command
`ALTER TABLE "installation_sites" DROP CONSTRAINT "installation_sites_contractor_id_fkey"` initially it couldn't find the constraint but i ran again and the answer was `found null row` and the constraint was gone.
I ran again my server and several repeated keys of installation_sites_contractor_id_fkey were created and then sequelize started complaining about others fkeys. I still can`t comprehend this behaviour

Comment: Did you check if you have `installation_sites_contractor_id_fkey` foreign key in DB?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be

Comment: Ok. Did you try to manually execute `ALTER TABLE "installation_sites" DROP CONSTRAINT "installation_sites_contractor_id_fkey"`?

Comment: I explained better what happened in the edited body of my question @Anatoly

Comment: Maybe you should try to indicate both keys in `belongsToMany`: `foreignKey` and `otherKey`

Comment: but between InstallationSite and Contractor there is only belongsTo and hasMany

Comment: My bad. I confused it with `installation_sites_intallation_site_id`

Comment: Try two cases: 1. recreate foreign keys after commenting two associations between `InstallationSite` and `Contractor and 2. recreate foreign keys after commenting `references` option for `contractor_id` field in `InstallationSite` model. Compare two results